# Initialize a lot of key/value from database

Tags: c#, reference, key-value

I have a lot of key/value pairs that I want to initialize. These pairs are stored in a database in field *Key* and field *Value* respectively. In a class, I have some class variables(for example):

```
private double _A = 10;
private double _B = 20;
```

I want to use a dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<string, double> pairs = new Dictionary<string, double>() { {"A", _A}, {"B", _B} };
```

So that I can use:

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, double> pair in pairs.toList() )
{
    pairs[pair.key] = GetValueFromDB(pair.key);
}
```

I am hoping that the class variables will be updated to the new values. Apparently it didn't work. I know the fundamental problem is it is double is not a reference type. I did try to use object, thinking that boxing will give me a reference to the value. It didn't work either.

My question is: what is the easiest way to initialize these class variables without using something like:

```
double tempValue;
tempValue = GetValueFromDB("A");

if (HasValueInDB("A"))
{
    _A = GetValueFromDB("A");
}
else
{
    InsertValueToDB("A", _A);
}
```

because I have about 40 class variables, and I think this is clumsy.

EDIT: A complete code:

```
private double _A=10;
private double _B=20;

public MainWindow()
{
    Dictionary<string, double> pairs = new Dictionary<string, double>() { { "A", _A }, { "B", _B } };
    InitializeComponent();
    Console.WriteLine("Before: " + _A);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> pair in pairs.ToList())
    {
        pairs[pair.Key] = GetValueFromDB(pair.Key);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("After: " + _A);    // expect _A to be 50, but it's still 10
}

private double GetValueFromDB(string key)
{
    return 50;
}
```

Comment: martin why do you want to have a class for this , or that you need the class for other reasons too

Comment: @tariq This is my ViewModel class. _A and _B are used for binding.

Comment: no i mean you can just create a dictionary and fill it with key values from DB and use it , why is this class involved. does it have any other function also ?

Comment: @tariq I have a default value for each variable. If the key is already in the db, then I want to fetch its value to use it. If the key is not in the db yet, I want to create a new instance in the db.

Say I create a dictionary and fill it with the key/value from db. How do I update the variables without using the clumsy way: using 40  statements, one for each variable.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Post code for `GetValueFromDB` please. You are not passing double anywhere, you are assigning to it woth this line `pairs[pair.key] = GetValueFromDB(pair.key);` and it could work depending on that method.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek The problem is not related to GetValueFromDB. I edited my question to clarify the point.

Comment: If you check `pairs["A"]` instead of `_A`, that value *will* have changed. As you *copied* the value of `_A` into that initial `pairs`, that `_A` value isn't changed when you update the `pairs` value.

Comment: @HansKesting Yes, that's where I have problem. I want to change _A, but how?

Comment: @Martin: i think you can come with a cleaner design, where you directly fill the dictionary with the values - either from the DB or using the default value if they are not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't come up with any other solution that this one using reflection. First of all, shove your fields to some class you can create instance of and use it like you wish. I made them public just for the sake of easy printing, feel free to let them be private.

```
class SomeValues
{
    public double _A = 10;
    public double _B = 20;

    public FieldInfo[] GetMyFields()
    {
        return GetType().GetFields();
    }
}
```

In case you make them private, you have to change the return line to

```
GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Create an instance of that class.

```
SomeValues values = new SomeValues();
```

If you make your field names match names in your db then this method will suffice. To update values from db, just call

```
foreach (var field in values.GetMyFields())
{
    var dbValue = GetValueFromDB(field.Name);
    field.SetValue(values, dbValue);
}
```

I think that this is much more clear than making a dictionary with 50 entries in it, which don't even work, because `double` is a value type and is passed by a value, not reference.